# active according base on page/file name

Tags: php, jquery, accordion

in my project have one according menu H2
if i click any menu name H2 then its open and show subment. now by default it's 1st ***(Governing Body)*** open..so when i click any link  say like **Add Gallery** it's go to that page  and **Gallery Management** will be open (active) and rest of will be close. Now always open 1st one ***(Governing Body)*** ..

how could I do that. Any idea. Jquery or php no problem. I just make it work…

please check this http://jsfiddle.net/KM4w6/

```
$(document).ready(function(){


//sub menu  
//Set default open/close settings
$('.acc_container').hide(); //Hide/close all containers
//$('.acc_trigger:first').addClass('active').next().show(); //Add "active" class to first trigger, then show/open the immediate next container

//On Click
$('.acc_trigger').click(function(){
    if( $(this).next().is(':hidden') ) { //If immediate next container is closed...
        $('.acc_trigger').removeClass('active').next().slideUp(); //Remove all .acc_trigger classes and slide up the immediate next container
        $(this).toggleClass('active').next().slideDown(); //Add .acc_trigger class to clicked trigger and slide down the immediate next container
    }
    return false; //Prevent the browser jump to the link anchor
});

}); 




 <div class="navarea">
  <h2 class="acc_trigger">Governing Body</h2>
  <div class="acc_container">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="new_position.php">Add Position</a></li>
      <li><a href="list_position.php">Edit/Delete Position</a></li>
      <li><a href="new_member.php">Add Member</a></li>
      <li><a href="list_member.php">Edit/Delete Member</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <h2 class="acc_trigger">Gallery Managment</h2>
  <div class="acc_container">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="new_gallery_info.php">Add Gallery</a></li>
      <li><a href="list_gallery_info.php">Edit/Delete Gallery</a></li>
      <li><a href="list_gallery_images.php">Gallery Images Management</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>

   <h2 class="acc_trigger">Other</h2>
   <div class="acc_container">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="cms.php?page='about_us'">About Us</a></li>
    <li><a href="new_link.php">Add Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="list_link.php">Edit/Delete Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="new_event.php">Add Event</a></li>
    <li><a href="list_event.php">Edit/Delete Event</a></li>
  </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you please try rephrasing this question. I understand English may not be your first language, but it is quite difficult to understand what you're trying to acheive

Comment: Please post the relevant code here. JSFiddle can be used as an additional demonstration, but the question should contain enough code to allow us to troubleshoot the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a different page/url to detect, you can do something like this:

```
if(window.location.indexOf('_gallery')>0){
   $('.acc_trigger:contains("Gallery Managment")').click();
} else if(window.location.indexOf('_position')>0 || window.location.indexOf('_member')>0){
   $('.acc_trigger:contains("Governing Body")').click();
}
```

[Edited fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NPma9/2/).

Comment: thanks @ agrothe....i am very new. so don't understand what i write in Gallery. i tried with file name like ('new_gallery_info.php') and many othwe way.. but its not work for me. yes u r right. i have page and url.. url like http://xxxxx.com/cms/new_gallery.info.php

Comment: @AccoreLTD I updated the answer a bit to reflect your naming. Put this in a jQuery.ready block and your all set. You will need to fill in the 'other' if block as well.

Answer (score 0):

it's like this way. i checked. is that proper way to do ...  or have any other nice way.

```
if( location.href.match("new_gallery_info.php") ){
   $('.acc_trigger:contains("Gallery Managment")').click();

}
```

Comment: this will work, but you will need more if statements, one for each URL as opposed to my answer of just matching a unique keyword.